# Existence of low temperature phase in 2-Dimensional XY-Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, correlation-functions, goldstone-mode

I'm reading the [lecture notes of David Tong on Statistical Field Theory](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html), specifically chapter $4.4$ on the Kosterlitz-Thouless Transition. He considers the XY model in $d=2$ dimensions and states the following:

In the high temperature phase, we work with the complex field. The free energy
has a quadratic term $\mu^2$ and, as we’ve now seen many times the correlation function decays exponentially:

\begin{equation}
\langle \psi^{\dagger}(x)\psi(0) \rangle =\frac{e^{\frac{-r}{\xi}}}{\sqrt{r}}
\end{equation}

with $\xi \sim 1/\mu^2$. Where $\xi$ is the correlation length.

So far so good for me. He then continues saying:

In contrast, in the low temperature phase we have $\mu^2 < 0$ and we can write $\psi = Me^{i\theta}$, with the long distance physics dominated by $\theta$. To leading order, we can write the free energy as

\begin{equation}
F[\theta]=\frac{1}{2e^2}\int d^2x (\nabla\theta)^2.
\end{equation}

Very low temperatures correspond to $e^2 << 1$.

He then goes on to say that the correlation function for this Goldstone mode is:

\begin{equation}
\langle \theta(x)\theta(0)\rangle=-\frac{e^2}{2\pi}\log(\Lambda r)
\end{equation}

concluding that:

\begin{equation}
\langle e^{i\theta(x)}e^{i\theta(0)}\rangle \sim \frac{1}{r^{\eta}}.
\end{equation}

This is where I get confused. The Mermin-Wagner theorem states that in $d=2$ dimensions there is no Spontaneous Symmetry breaking happening. Therefore I don't see how it makes sense to speak of a low temperature phase with $\mu^2 < 0$ to begin with. How can these conclusions therefore be valid?

Comment: Mermin-Wagner is about long-range order, whereas BKT is related to topological phase transition and it is about algebraic order. The correlator decays algebraically, instead of exp decay

Comment: Yes but the algebraic decay of the last equation is derived by assuming there is a finite critical temperature which shouldn't happen according to Mermin-Wagner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the algebraic decay of correlation function is obtained in spin-wave approximation, which does not imply SSB at finite $T$, but implies that at sufficiently low $T$ the spin direction varies very little from site to site.

I would to add some details to the presented answer. I am not sure that I correctly understand your confusion, but let me try to explain. First of all, we write the Hamiltonian for XY-model,
$$H_{\text{XY}}=-J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j),$$
where we have setted unit legnth of spin vector and $J>0$ is the coupling constant. Angular brackets means summation over nearest neighbors on square 2D lattice. We are interested in the following correlation function,
$$C(0,r)\equiv\langle {\bf S}_0\cdot{\bf S}_{\bf r}\rangle\equiv \langle e^{i(\theta_{{\bf r}}-\theta_{0})}\rangle,$$
where indices denote coordinats at square lattice. This correlation function will tell me about a possibility to have the order in XY-model. What we can say right now:

1. The Hamiltonian is minimized by choosing $\theta_i\equiv \theta_j$. We can say that $\forall i$, $\theta_i = \theta_{0}$, where $\theta_0\in[0,2\pi)$. This is so-called ferromagnetic phase, which corresponds to broken $\text{U}(1)$ (or $\text{O}(2)$, if one prefers) symmetry. For this state $C(0,r)\equiv 1$. Naively, this state is realized at zero $T$, $\beta\rightarrow\infty$.
2. At finite $T$, if
   $$\lim\limits_{|{\bf r}|\rightarrow\infty}C(0,r)>0$$
   implies that the system is ordered, i.e. long-range order (LRO) exists and spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) takes place at *finite* temperature $T$. If the system is not ordered, we expect that
   $$\lim\limits_{|{\bf r}|\rightarrow\infty}C(0,r)\sim \exp\left\{-\frac{|{\bf r}|}{\xi}\right\},$$
   where $\xi$ is a correlationg length.

Now we compute this correlation function. To do it, we first analyze the partition function,
$$\mathcal{Z}_{\text{XY}}\sim\int\mathcal{D}{\bf S}\exp\left\{+\beta J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}{\bf S}_i\cdot{\bf S}_j\right\}.$$
As was stated above, at low-T we expect that difference $\theta_i-\theta_j$ becomes smaller and smaller (at $T=0$ we expect $\theta_i\equiv\theta_j$), so at very low-T, we can expand
$$\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\approx 1 - \frac{(\theta_i-\theta_j)^2}{2}+\text{higher terms}.$$
Next, we take the continuum limit and write
$$\theta_i-\theta_j \rightarrow +\nabla_{\mu}\theta,$$
where the lattice spacing $a$ was omitted and $\mu=\{x,y\}$. It is so-called *spin-wave approximation*. In this approximation, the final expression for the correlation function looks like
$$C(0,r)\sim\left(\frac{a}{|{\bf r}|}\right)^{1/(2\pi K)},$$
where the lattice spacing $a$ was restored. This expression is valid at low-T. Let us check $r\rightarrow\infty$ limit behavior. We see that due to 2D, the correlation function decays *algebraically*. It means that SSB does not occur at *finite* low-T.

In case of high-T phase, the inverse temperature is small ($\beta=1/T$) and I can expand the exp in the partition function into Taylor series. The final form of this expansion looks like
$$\langle {\bf S}_0\cdot{\bf S}_{\bf r}\rangle\sim \prod_{i}^N\int\frac{d\theta_i}{2\pi}\cos(\theta_0-\theta_r)\prod_{\langle i,j\rangle}\left\{1+K\cos(\theta_i-\theta_r)+\mathcal{O}(K^2)\right\},$$
where $K=\beta J$ is assumed to be small. After some derivations, one can show that
$$\langle {\bf S}_0\cdot{\bf S}_{\bf r}\rangle\approx \left(\frac{K}{2}\right)^{-|{\bf r}|}=e^{-|{\bf r}|/\xi},\quad \xi\equiv \frac{1}{\ln(2/K)}.$$
We see that the system is not ordered.

We can summarize our findings:

|  | low-T phase | high-T phase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no SSB, $D=2$ | algebraic order | no order |
| true SSB, $D>2$ | long-range order | no order |

This is in accordance with Mermin-Wagner theorem: there is no SSB for short-range interactions in 2D at *finite* temperature.

Comment: My confusion arises from what you call the low-T phase. The way I understand it low-T is below the critical temperature, the temperature at which SSB is bound to happen. But if there is no SSB the critical temperature is at zero. Doesn't that mean that the low-T phase should be below zero?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the approximation that you can expand the cosine term at low temperatures or equivalently that $\psi=Me^{i\theta}$ and take the leading term in the free energy, is not related to SSB?

Comment: I'm again confused. Setting $\psi=Me^{i\theta}$ implies SSB, we do the calculation for the correlation function and we get that it's $\sim r^{-\eta}$, that's in contradiction with SSB therefore we conclude that there is no SSB, but we still accept that the correlation function is $\sim r^{-\eta}$ ?

Comment: @ΜπαμπηςΠοζουκιδης I have again modified the answer, sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

Hohenberg-Mermin-Wagner (HMW) theorem states that you cannot have spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) of a continuous symmetry at finite temperature in $d \leq 2$.

The low-temperature phase of the 2d XY model does not spontaneously break the $U(1)$ symmetry. It has algebraic order in the correlation function $\sim \mathcal{O}(r^{-\eta})$, not long-range order $\sim \mathcal{O}(1)$ which signals SSB.

The existence of a different low-temperature phase for the XY model is not violating Hohenberg-Mermin-Wagner theorem, since the phase does not spontaneously break the $U(1)$ symmetry.

---

Some historical context: The motivation for Kosterlitz and Thouless to think about this problem is that HMW apparently prohibits superfluidity in 2 dimensions, but superfluidity was seen experimentally in thin films! This led to their explanation of the BKT phase transition, where the transition happens due to proliferation of defects (vortices), and distinct from Landau's paradigm of symmetry breaking.